Extracting elements from json string using spark SQL queries
I am new to spark sql and am trying to extract element from json string with get_json_object().
The name of the table is abc.
This is my json string
dns_flip_details = "{'flipDetails': [{'ServiceFqdn': 'fqdn1' 'StartTime': 2024-09-09 11:55:11.546052+00:00, 'EndTime': 2024-09-10 11:55:11.546052+00:00}, {'ServiceFqdn': 'fqdn2','StartTime': 2024-09-11 11:55:11.546052+00:00, 'EndTime': 2024-09-12 11:55:11.546052+00:00}]}"

I want to extract the last EndTime from this.
For extracting the 1st one, the below query works:
select (get_json_object(dns_flip_details,"$.flipDetails[0].EndTime")) as 1st_end_date from abc

I tried using array_size() as below but it does not seem to be working
select (get_json_object(dns_flip_details,"$.flipDetails[array_size($.flipDetails[*])-1].EndTime")) as last_end_date from abc

Any help here would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

After trying a multiple things like explode(), from_json(), array_size() and after almost giving up
Note:
While this method attempts to use get_json_object(), it involves some workarounds since get_json_object() does not natively support array indexing. To get just last EndTime, consider whether using from_json() or another method might be more straightforward.
Here is the code:
create temporary view json_data as
(select get_json_object(dns_flip_details,"$.flipDetails") as flipDetails from abc);
cache table json_data;

select get_json_object(flipDetails, '$[' || (size(split(flipDetails, '},')) - 1) || '].EndTime') as LastEndTime from json_data
;


